# My Date formatting keeps adding extra Numbers at the End

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I am formatting a date as follows:

```
Y17W11
```

Which is easy enough to do, except the cell that I am putting it in seems to be formatted weirdly and keeps correcting my date into:

```
Y17W112
```

Even when I enter the exact string "Y17W11" into the cell it turns into "Y17W112". Right clicking and changing basic formatting doesn't seem to do anything (I've tried switching it to date, text, currency, etc).

I figure there's something stupid I've missed that's auto formatting it.

Thanks!

Comment: What exact *format string* are you using for the cell in question? Please [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: If you are converting a date to year(date) and weeknum(date,1) it will automatically calculate whatever format you are setting

Comment: I'm literally just typing Y17W11 into a cell without using any formatting. I bumped into this problem in an attempt to format so I've dumbed it down to find the root!

Comment: For some reason whenever you change a format in Excel, it will not change it unless you refresh the cell. I usually press F2, ENTER after changing a cell's format. Or double click to activate it, then enter. Refreshes the cell.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like auto-correct. You can turn auto-correct off altogether or just delete the offending item from the list. You can do that like this:

File > Options > Proofing > Auto-Correct options

See [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/questions/auto_correct2010.php) for 2010 instructions - I assume it's similar in Excel 2013

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who has this problem. I just had the same situation happen to me. It was because the same date was found on the chart twice.

I had a spreadsheet where i was entering in a new set of dates - this was a spreadsheet that I was **re-using** from one year to the next ***and*** the last date was a cross over with the end of the previous year ***and*** the beginning of the new. When i saved the old spreadsheet to begin entering data for the new upcoming year, the ending date of the year i was just finishing was 8/15/19. As i began entering the new dates to this new year spreadsheet, the 1st date of the new year was also 8/15/19 - the spreadsheet kept adding a 2 to the end of that particular column date- 8/15/20192. This ended up being because the end of the spreadsheet still had 8/15/2019 as a date. I changed the ending date to 8/15/2020 on the new spreadsheet and the system no longer kept adding a 2 to the start date of 8/15/2019.